# Deploy Kubernetes using Helm and Jenkins for Microservice Based Application

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We are developing an web application which had a multiple micro-services in same repository.

For our existing monolithic application, we are deploying our application to Kubernetes using Helm and Jenkins. When micro-services in question, we are struggling to define our CI/CD Pipeline strategies. Belows are the unclear issues:

- For monolithic application I have one Dockerfile, one Jenkinsfile and one Helm Chart. For building stage I am building image/s using following command.

  ```
  docker.build("registry/myrepo/image:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
  ```
- For monolithic application, I have one chart with multiple values.yaml such as values.dev.yaml, values.prod.yaml which I configured for multiple environments.

So our questions are;

1.How should we build and push multiple containers for multiple Dockerfiles in Jenkinsfile for micro-services? At the present every micro-services have their own Dockerfiles in their own root.

2.Is that possible for Jenkins to distinguish the micro-services that we would like to deploy? I mean,sometimes probably we made some changes only for specific service and we would like to deploy this changes. So should we organize independent pipeline or is there any way to handle this same pipeline?

3.How should we organize our Helm chart to deploy micro-services Kubernetes? Should we create multiple charts per services or create multiple templates that refers only one values.yaml?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are almost there.

1. Have separate pipelines for micro services, this would build, verify and deploy docker images to a docker registry. Have a separate pipeline for verifying and deploying the whole stack using helm.
2. I assume you would be using git events to identify the changes? When there is change in a microservice, I assume it would be committed to a single repository. This would trigger a git event using which you can trigger the pipeline of the respective microservice.
3. As the helm represents your whole application stack,  I would suggest to have it as a single chart. If the complexity of the micro service is getting increased split it as subcharts.

Multiple charts can be a future maturity level when teams associated with each microservice can deploy the upgrades independently without affecting availability of the whole stack.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry to ask twice but I guess you are also suggest to separate pipelines per micro-services, am I correct?For the seconds answer, right now we have only one repository and is that possible to solve this single repository?

Comment: Well in principle a micro service means an (or a way to) independent existence. Ideally the entire organisation should be structured like that. But when we are starting with we may start small

Comment: Specific to keeping a single repo, it is possible. You should have a mechanism filtering the events according to package in the changeset. I think a small script can help here

Comment: Also keep in mind this is a point to revisit your microservice strategy. If your services cannot be separated at the git repo level, are you doing the right level of split ? And if the answer is that you have enough reason to go forward.. please do so.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have separate job in jenkins for each microservice.
2. Have a separate job to deploy the whole application using Helm chart

Comment: So we should locate them separate repositories, am I correct?

Comment: yes. have seperate repo for each microservice and one for helm chart

Comment: Can't we handle this using one repository.Is that a silly solution or impossible? I saw some examples that handle multiple templates refer to one values.yaml but I could not find any information how to handle the rest of the items in Jenkins :)

Comment: if you put all services in one repo then how do you build. It would be possible and but difficult to manage. you would lose modularity. if one service code is changed then check-in happens to whole repo, you might not know which service was updated. Each time you need to build all microservices